# How can merge objects if objects id is same?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to merge objects wich has same id.

I am getting javascript objects as a string from mysql with php:

```
$sql="SELECT plaka,il,SUM(hasta_say) AS Hasta_Say FROM ADSM GROUP BY plaka,il ORDER BY Hasta_Say ";

///COLUMN CHARTS

$result=$baglanti->query($sql);
$ilEventChart="";
while ($query=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$color=random_color();  


$ilEventChart.='
columnChartData.TR'.$query['plaka'].' = [
        {
        "il": "'.$query['il'].'",
        "hasta_sayisi":'.$query['Hasta_Say'].',
        "color": "'.$color.'"
        }];
';
}
```

So I am printing to `$ilEventChart` php variable to javascript area.

After this javascript Objects created Like this.But recursive 'plaka' causing recursive objects with different properties.

Here Objects:

```
columnChartData.TR78 = [
        {
        "il": "KARABÜK",
        "hasta_sayisi":66148,
        "color": "b2147e"
        }];

columnChartData.TR78 = [
        {
        "il": "ÇANAKKALE",
        "hasta_sayisi":66246,
        "color": "9a720a"
        }];
```

I want to merge this objects as a one object.Desired output like this:

```
columnChartData.TR78 = [
        {
        "il": "KARABÜK",
        "hasta_sayisi":66148,
        "color": "b2147e"
        },
        {
        "il": "ÇANAKKALE",
        "hasta_sayisi":66246,
        "color": "9a720a"
        }];
```

How can we do this with javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Are those two different array objects TR78? I'm assuming they're not supposed to be the same variable name, right? Are you trying to merge objects from two different arrays together?

Comment: I am getting data from php.And Sam ids coming.So Output has with same ids objects.I want to merge wich has same id objects

Comment: How are you getting the data? AJAX? Is *columnChartData* a variable or object property?

Comment: What field are you considering as `id`? `il`?

Comment: id is objects name properties.TR78 is id

Comment: You need to explain how you are getting the data from PHP. Where is `columnChartData` declared? Please show the code in context.

Answer (score 0):

After long working I found the solution.Solution possible with using PHP Arrays.

Here is Solution:

1. We Define `birim` MultiDimensional Array for using javascript
   id(plaka).
2. After We get datas from MySQL with while loop and push the every
   datas to `birim` array
3. So we created a multidimensional array with id number wich has own
   key.For example if we check the array wtih `print_r`:

   echo '

   ```
   ';
   print_r($birim[6]);
   ```

We saw about id of `6` values in array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA GÃ–LBAÅI AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":70518,
        "color": "e817c0"
        },
    [1] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA SÄ°NCAN AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":77868,
        "color": "ac31aa"
        },
    [2] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA BALGAT AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":97564,
        "color": "609724"
        },
    [3] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA KEÃ‡Ä°Ã–REN OSMANLI AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":97773,
        "color": "62f1a0"
        },
    [4] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA MAMAK AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":126806,
        "color": "2c7498"
        },
    [5] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA TOPRAKLIK AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI MERKEZÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":126854,
        "color": "23a203"
        },
    [6] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA TEPEBAÅI AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI HASTANESÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":200623,
        "color": "735aa6"
        },
    [7] => {
        "birim": "ANKARA 75.YIL AÄIZ VE DÄ°Å SAÄLIÄI HASTANESÄ°",
        "hasta_sayisi":260057,
        "color": "4d8cd1"
        },
)
```

4. After all this we printing array values `foreach loop` to temp
   variable which we will use in javascript code.

Here is Full Codes:

`$sql="SELECT plaka,birim,SUM(hasta_say) AS Hasta_Say FROM ADSM GROUP BY birim ORDER BY Hasta_Say "; 
    $result=$baglanti->query($sql);
    $birimEventChart="";

    $birim=array();

    while ($query=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $color=random_color();  


    $birim[$query['plaka']][]='{
            "birim": "'.$query['birim'].'",
            "hasta_sayisi":'.$query['Hasta_Say'].',
            "color": "'.$color.'"
            },';
    }




    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT plaka FROM ADSM";
    $result=$baglanti->query($sql);
    $temp="";
    while ($query=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

        foreach ($birim[$query['plaka']] as $p) {
            $temp.=$p;
        }   


        $birimEventChart.='hastaneChartData.TR'.$query['plaka'].' = ['.$temp.'];';
        $temp="";
    }`